# How can I determine if Android phone uses a gesture or pin to unlock the phone?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I would like to know if the user uses either a pin or a gesture to unlock his device.

Until now I have only been able to find solutions in which they use `Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED`.

However this was deprecated for `Android M`, and trying to use it on `Android M` will throw a `SecurityException`.

So is there a way to know what type of unlock method is being used?

Comment: Try `DevicePolicyManager`.